# Writing SQL Query to retrieve data via a Subquery?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I need to write a query to retrieve values that respect the following condition,

> Select Users from UserTable that I am (me@gmail.com) not friends with

Here are my table formats:

[image]

My email is stated at UserID and my friends are stated in the FriendID column. I need to select the users from the UserTable that are not listed as friends in the FriendsTable. Seems like a simple query but I couldn't figure it out. Here's what I tried:

**P.S:** I just wrote this for clarification and therefore I **don't** want to write a parameterized query. I am not planning on distributing this.

```
SELECT * From UserTable  WHERE Email NOT LIKE '% (Select FriendsTable.FriendID From FriendsTable Where FriendsTable.UserID='me@gmail.com') %'
```

**EDIT**

jpw's query worked. However, how do I retrieve one random row from his solution's query?

This doesn't work:

```
select TOP 1 * from UserTable where UserTable.Email <> '" + email + "' and Email not in (select case when FriendsTable.UserID = '" + email + "' then FriendsTable.FriendID else UserID end from FriendsTable where '" + email + "' in (UserID, FriendID)); ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the friend relationship can go both ways and you want to exclude not only rows where email = 'me@gmail.com' but also rows where FriendID = 'me@gmail.com', that is, both rows below

```
UserID            FriendID
me@gmail.com      ddaabb@gmail.com
kk@gmail.com      me@gmail.com
```

then this query will do that:

```
select * 
from userTable
where Email <> 'me@gmail.com'
  and Email not in (
    select 
      case 
       when UserID = 'me@gmail.com' 
       then FriendID else UserID 
      end 
    from FriendsTable 
    where 'me@gmail.com' in (UserID, FriendID)
  );
```

Even if you only want to exclude those users that occur in the FriendID column this will still work, although there are better ways in that case.

With your sample data the result would be:

```
kk@gmail.com
yybb@gmail.com
```

Or you do this:

```
select * from
UserTable u
where u.Email <> 'me@gmail.com' and
not exists (
    select 1 from FriendsTable
    where FriendID = u.Email
  );
```

Comment: No mate I just want to get the people that I'm not following :) Not bothways

Comment: btw how do I exclude my own email from the results? Could your solution return my own email since it doesnt exist as a friend? I need to exclude my email

Comment: Perfect! I have one last clarification about your query. Could you check my question edit please?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM USERTABLE U WHERE U.EMAIL <> 'ME@GMAIL.COM' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FRIENDSTABLE WHERE FRIENDID = U.EMAIL) ORDER BY NEWID();`

Comment: @Earthling Maybe that is what you're looking for?

Comment: So the initial query changed now? Can I add the TOP 1 statement to the query I edited in the question? (Your first solution)

Comment: @Earthling The only reason the query you edited in doesn't work is that there is a semi-colon `;` before the order by. Remove that and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh wow thanks man. That did the trick neat and clean. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to check that the `Email` not present in `friends` table like below

```
select * from
UserTable ut
where not exists (
select 1 from FriendsTable
where UserID != ut.Email)
and ut.Email = 'me@gmail.com';
```

Another solution is to use a `LEFT JOIN` and choose the `NULL` like

```
select ut.*
from UserTable ut
left join FriendsTable ft on ut.Email = ft.UserID
where ft.UserID is null and ut.Email = 'me@gmail.com';
```

Comment: so ut.Email would be me@gmail.com?

Comment: @Earthling, it will select all those records where the email doesn't exists in friend table.

Comment: Where would I add 'me@gmail.com'?

Comment: It returned an error:

The multi-part identifier "UserTable.UserID" could not be bound.

Comment: Add another condition in `WHERE` clause. See edit in answer if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for all users who are not friends of a single user, then try this:

```
select t.Email
from UserTable as t
left join FriendsTable as f on f.UserID=t.Email
where f.UserID IS NULL and t.Email='me@gmail.com'
```

Comment: This didn't return any users, mate

Comment: That's because me@gmail.com is in the FriendsTable. Try another user from UserTable that is not the FriendsTable in the final **t.Email='me@gamil.com'** part of the query to get the correct answer.